# Mapper output key descending order

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop. So far, I am trying to implement a custom writable comparator to sort my map output keys, which is DoubleWritable, in descending order. Below is my comparator class:

```
class DecreasingComparator extends WritableComparator{
        protected DecreasingComparator(){
            super(DoubleWritable.class,true);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable w1,WritableComparable w2){
            DoubleWritable key1 = (DoubleWritable) w1;
            DoubleWritable key2 = (DoubleWritable) w2;
            return -1 * key1.compareTo(key2);
        }
    }
```

The output I'm getting is this:

[image: output]

By right, it should be sorted in descending order by key. Why is it still ordered by the value, which is IntWritable?

It can't be an issue with the Mapper class since it just outputs the key and values. I'm not sure how to go about this. The Mapper class is as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class SecondaryMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,DoubleWritable,IntWritable>{

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        String line = value.toString();
        DoubleWritable ratio = new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(line.split("\\s")[0]));
        IntWritable id = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\s")[1]));
        context.write(ratio,id);
    }
}
```

Below is my driver class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

//second job import


public class CommentViewRatio {
    
    class DecreasingComparator extends WritableComparator{
        protected DecreasingComparator(){
            super(DoubleWritable.class,true);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable w1,WritableComparable w2){
            DoubleWritable key1 = (DoubleWritable) w1;
            DoubleWritable key2 = (DoubleWritable) w2;
            return -1 * key1.compareTo(key2);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length != 2){
            System.out.printf("Usage: WordCount <input dir> <output dir>\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf1);
        
        job.setJarByClass(CommentViewRatio.class);
        job.setJobName("Average");
        Path temp = new Path("temp");
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,  temp);
        
        job.setMapperClass(CommentViewMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
//      job.setPartitionerClass(CommentViewPartitioner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CommentViewReducer.class);
//      job.setNumReduceTasks(4);
        
        job.setOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        if(success) {
            Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
            Job job2 = new Job(conf2);
            job2.setJarByClass(CommentViewRatio.class);
            
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("temp/part-r-00000"));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
            
            
            job2.setMapperClass(SecondaryMapper.class);
            job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
            job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
//          job2.setPartitionerClass(CommentViewPartitioner.class);
            job2.setSortComparatorClass(DecreasingComparator.class);
            job2.setNumReduceTasks(0);

            
            boolean success2 = job2.waitForCompletion(true);
            temp.getFileSystem(conf1).delete(temp);
            System.exit(success2 ? 0 : 1);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I needed to add a reducer class for my output to be sorted if I want to use a custom sort comparator.

The new driver looks like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

//second job import

public class CommentViewRatio {
    
    public static class DecreasingComparator extends WritableComparator{
        protected DecreasingComparator(){
            super(DoubleWritable.class,true);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public int compare(WritableComparable w1,WritableComparable w2){
            DoubleWritable key1 = (DoubleWritable) w1;
            DoubleWritable key2 = (DoubleWritable) w2;
            return -1 * key1.compareTo(key2);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length != 2){
            System.out.printf("Usage: WordCount <input dir> <output dir>\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf1);
        
        job.setJarByClass(CommentViewRatio.class);
        job.setJobName("Average");
        Path temp = new Path("temp");
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,  temp);
        
        job.setMapperClass(CommentViewMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
//      job.setPartitionerClass(CommentViewPartitioner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CommentViewReducer.class);
//      job.setNumReduceTasks(4);
        
        job.setOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        if(success) {
            Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
            Job job2 = new Job(conf2);
            job2.setJarByClass(CommentViewRatio.class);
            
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("temp/part-r-00000"));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
            
            
            job2.setMapperClass(SecondaryMapper.class);
            job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
            job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
          //job2.setPartitionerClass(CommentViewPartitioner.class);
            job2.setSortComparatorClass(DecreasingComparator.class);
            
            job2.setReducerClass(SecondaryReducer.class);
            job2.setOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
            job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            
          //job2.setNumReduceTasks(4);
            
            boolean success2 = job2.waitForCompletion(true);
            temp.getFileSystem(conf1).delete(temp);
            System.exit(success2 ? 0 : 1);
        }
        
    }
}
```

All you need to do is implement a reducer class for the output to be sorted. Weird considering how some sources say that WritableComparator sorts the map output, not the reducer output.